# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*' in string function

Tags: c++

If argument doesn't fit to format, I want to throw message. I actually don't know what happen. I tried to throw message with std::string but doesn't work. What's going on there?

In addition, compiler gave "abort called" message.

I searched the topic before opening it, but I could not found a satisfactory answer.

```
string timeConversion(string s) {
    // hh:mm:ss:AM
    if(s.length() != 11)
        throw "message";

    return something;
}
```

Edit: The code simplified.

Comment: You should not throw build-in types, but instances of classes that ultimately inherit from `std::exception`. Either create your own class or [use one of the provided classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception). Could you please elaborate a bit on your problem? The throw probably comes from your own code.

Comment: This code is about hackerrank. I am trying to solve a question. And I am writing a code in timeConversion() function.

Comment: You are not throwing a `std::string`. You are throwing a pointer-decayed string literal, i.e. a `const char*`. There is also no `catch` anywhere in the shown code. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @David I rewrote it slightly. I hope it doesn't sound sarcastic anymore. But that is a honest question. I don't know what OP is expecting the `throw` lines to do. Either they *did* intend to throw a `std::string` and are catching it somewhere else (which they should show) or they actually just want to `return` or something completely different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't throw strings (`const char*`):

```
throw "failed because of hour";
```

make an exception `class`:

```
class MyException : public std::exception
{
public:
    MyException(const char* err) : std::exception(err) {}       
};
```

and `throw` that:

```
throw MyException("failed because of hour");
```

and then `catch` it:

```
try
{
    // code that might throw
}
catch(const MyException& ex)
{
    // process exception
}
```

if an exception is thrown and not caught (your current case) then `terminate` is called.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I have to little change it. Because when I used to code, I received `No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::exception'`. Then I defined private string and used it instead of std::exception(err). Also I deleted `&` in constructor parameter because give me another errors. And then it worked.

Comment: Sorry, forgot `std:: exception` takes a `const char*` editted answer. And your totally welcome. :-)